# Viewer Elements broken after integrating ant design

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

i just played around with ant design and i noticed that ant design global styles override all element inside the dom.
So after integrating ant, the viewer toolbar changed while the model-browser is unchanged.
[image]
[image]

Overriding with

```
.adsk-viewing-viewer * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box !important;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box !important;
  box-sizing: content-box !important; }
```

for all viewer elements is working only for the toolbar, and not for the model-browser.
[image]
[image]

The only way to fix this, is to disable box-sizing:border-box, but this is only working inside the browser and not in code.

Is anyone facing similar issues or knows a workaround?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is a known issue that we do not have an official solution for. When integrating Forge Viewer with 3rd party CSS frameworks you will have to manually override the styles for some of the viewer GUI components to bring their original style back.

In your specific case you may need to provide a new rule for the `.adsk-viewing-viewer input.search-box` selector to bring back its original style, e.g.:

```css
.adsk-viewing-viewer input.search-box {
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.94);
    border: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.8);
    height: 34px;
    direction: ltr;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 7px 12px 8px 40px;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 100%;
    outline: none;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    line-height: normal;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update:
Actually the search box is not the problem. I can get the original style by override the box-sizing for the viewer and for the search-box.

```
.adsk-viewing-viewer * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box !important;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box !important;
  box-sizing: content-box !important;
}
.adsk-viewing-viewer .adsk-searchbox input.search-box {
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
}
```

[image]

But i am not able to get the "leaf icon" and the hover size of all model-divs to work correctly.
[image]

UPDATE:
Just solved my question:
The problem is the box-sizing value. You will have to override it for each element which is missaligned.
Adding the following fixed my issue:

```
.adsk-viewing-viewer .treeview lmvheader {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box !important;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box !important;
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
}
```